# Get ID value from another page

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input

first , I use the code below to show data such as name , quotation id and user id etc etc from table quotation that contains customer id , I wanted to update table quotation and update wpids value in table corders based on the value of wid in table quotation . Thank you in advance for those who are willing to help

updatequo.php

```
<?php 
$qid =$_GET["qid"];
$query = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM quotation where qid = '$qid';");
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
?>
<form action='updatequo1.php?qid=<?php echo $qid;?>' method='post'>
<table align='center' width='45%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>

<tr>
  <td align='left' width='50%'>Quotation ID<td><input class='Minput'  type ='text' name='qid'value='<?php echo $result["qid"];?>' disabled ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align='left' width='30%'>User ID<td><input class='Minput'  type ='text' name='uid' value='<?php echo $result["uid"];?>' disabled ></td>
</tr>
```

but when i declare $uid = $_POST['uid']; in updatequo1.php but it says

> Notice: Undefined index: uid

in updatequo1.php i wanted to update the value of wpids and change it based on wid value

```
 $result=mysqli_query ($conn, " UPDATE corders set wpids = '$wid' where customerid = '$uid';");
```

Comment: You are open to SQL and XSS injections. Don't just trust user input. Don't use HTML tables for design, use CSS. What do the transmitted form fields end up sent as?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST);` say?

Comment: Editing the question is not how to mark it as resolved. Please post an answer, accept and answer (if one resoled your issue), or delete the question if it was just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Your input field is `disabled` please replace it with `readonly`. Disable field data can not be sent by post or get.

Comment: this is the answer to my question . thank you

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the `undefined` index is because you have the inputs `disabled`:

```
<input class='Minput'  type ='text' name='qid'value='<?php echo $result["qid"];?>' disabled >
<input class='Minput'  type ='text' name='uid' value='<?php echo $result["uid"];?>' disabled >
```

Change it from `disabled` to `readonly`.

Disabled inputs will not be sent to the back end on your `POST` request.